# Opening the start page after opening Xamarin UWP app via File Type Associations

Tags: xamarin, uwp, xamarin.uwp, file-type-associations

I have registered a File Type Associations to open my custom fileformat `.xoip`. When I'm opening a `.xoip` file the `OnFileActivated`-function in the App class gets started but no MainPage gets created.

Depending on the contact of the file, I want to decide in the `OnFileActivated`-function whether or not to start my start page. What do I have to call to start the start page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With File Type Association you need to manually specify what page to be loaded when a particular file is open.

When any associated file is activated it will call `OnFileActivated` of your App.xaml.cs. 
You can add your logic to navigate to a particular page in that method. Please refer to below code:

```
protected override void OnFileActivated(FileActivatedEventArgs args)
{
   base.OnFileActivated(args);
   var rootFrame = new Frame();
   rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), args);
   Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
   Window.Current.Activate();
}
```